# I can't understand how this javascript function works

Tags: javascript, logic

I was reading the [function definition of bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), but I can't 100% understand the code as written:

```
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
    Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
        if (typeof this !== "function") {
            // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5 internal IsCallable function
            throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");
        }

        var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
            fToBind = this,
            fNOP = function() {},
            fBound = function() {
                return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP
                                       ? this 
                                       : oThis || window,
                                     aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
            };

        fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
        fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

        return fBound;
    };
}
```

Specifically, I don't get the purpose of `fNOP`, and I don't understand why `fBound`'s prototype needs to be set. I am also hung up at the `fToBind.apply` part (I can't figure out what this represents in this context).

Can someone can explain what is going on here?

Comment: I need more Vodka "Smirnoff" to answer this question...

Comment: About halfway down on http://stage.learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/closures/, does that shed any insight?

Comment: I don't think it will help much, but for reference: [`Function.prototype.bind` specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_15.3.4.5).

Comment: @Davis It is NOT the definition of bind, it is a partial(!) workaround for older browsers.

Comment: Keep in mind that MDN is a wiki, and may be erroneous. This is where the code came from: https://developer.mozilla.org/index.php?title=en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind&action=diff&revision=31&diff=32

Comment: And here is a better implementation, with comprehensive comments: https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim/blob/master/es5-shim.js

Answer (score 6):

Well, one reason `fBound`'s prototype needs to be set is so that the result of calling `bind` on a function has the same prototype as that function. This is also where `fNop` seems to come in--it lets you set `fBound`'s prototype using `new fNop()` without calling the original function which may have side effects.

The call to `apply` lets you both set `this` in the function and specify additional arguments. Since `bind` lets you "curry" arguments to the function, you have to combine both the arguments passed in when the function is bound and the arguments it is called with.

Comment: instead of using fNop, why can't you just say fBound.prototype = this.prototype? I believe it has to do with why the instanceof fNop check is made, and that is the part I cannot reason through

Comment: The point is, `bind` *creates a function*. So it's defined just to be consistent with *declaring a function*, where a new object is assigned to that function's `prototype` property. I guess we could use `fBound.prototype = Object.create(this.prototype)` but that wouldn't make much sense, since `Object.create` is likely not to exist in browsers that don't know about `bind`.

Comment: "the result of calling bind on a function has the same prototype as that function." Actually, it's supposed to have no prototype at all, as [defined in ES5](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.5)

Answer (score 1):

It is to make sure

- (1) the bound function can be used as a constructor, ignoring the binding. (hence the `instanceof` check)
- (2) At the same time, you want to make sure that  `new g()` inherits from `f`'s prototype chain. (hence the `.prototype = new fNop` part)

Example:

```
function f() {
    this.foo = 'bar';
}
f.prototype = {
    baz: 'yay!'
};

var g = f.bind({});
var o = new g();
console.log(o.foo); // 'bar' - (1)
console.log(o.baz); // 'yay!' - (2)
```

At the moment you call `new g()`, the `fBound` function is called as a constuctor with a brand new object object (`this`) that is an instance of `fNop`.

---

### Edit:

The ECMAScript5 standard defines a complicated algorithm for binding functions. Amongst others, the following assertions must hold true:

```
var DateJan2042 = Date.bind(null, 2042, 0);

 /*1*/ console.assert(Function.prototype.bind.length == 1, 'bind should have a length of 1');
 /*2*/ console.assert(typeof DateJan2042 == 'function', 'bind() should return a function');
 /*3*/ console.assert(!DateJan2042.hasOwnProperty('prototype'), 'Bound function must not have a prototype');
 /*4*/ console.assert(DateJan2042.length == Math.max(Date.length - 2, 0), 'Bound function should have a proper length');
 /*5*/ console.assert(typeof DateJan2042() == 'string', 'Function call should return a string');
 /*6*/ console.assert({}.toString.call(new DateJan2042()).indexOf('Date') != -1, 'Constructor call should return a new Date object');
 /*7*/ console.assert(new DateJan2042() instanceof DateJan2042, 'Instanceof check should pass for constructor\'s return value');
 /*8*/ console.assert((new DateJan2042()).getMonth() == 0, 'Constructor should be called with bound arguments');
 /*9*/ console.assert((new DateJan2042(1)).getDate() == 1, 'Constructor should take additional arguments');
/*10*/ console.assert(!/^function *\( *[^ )]/.test(Function.prototype.toString.call(DateJan2042)), 'Bound function should have no formal arguments');
```

Since a properly bound function is not a real `Function` object, it's impossible to get it all right using a polyfill (Particularly numbers 2/3, and 4/10), but you can try to implement as much as possible.

The implementation in question tries to solve number 6 and number 7, by hooking into the prototype chain, but [that's not enough](http://jsfiddle.net/ADfwp/).

Here is an alternative implementation that works a bit better, but is still not perfect:
http://jsfiddle.net/YR6MJ/

Answer (score 0):

From an earlier comment:

> instead of using fNop, why can't you just say `fBound.prototype =
>   this.prototype`?

As far as I can tell, the primary difference is that when the value of `this` inside the bound function is an instance of the original function on which `bind` was invoked, then the value to bind to -- the first argument originally passed to `bind` -- is ignored.

For example, this code:

```
function Test(blah) {
    console.log(this.length, blah);
}

Test.prototype.length = 77;
Test.prototype.fn = Test.bind(['a', 'b', 'c'], "testing");
new Test().fn()
```

...causes `fn` to print:

```
77 testing
```

In other words, the value of `this` inside `fn` is the `Test` instance on which it was invoked. Your suggestion would supply the bound array to the `apply` inside `bind`, so, written that way, the last line of the same code would print:

```
3 testing
```

It's not completely clear to me *why* this is important, but it does highlight that your suggestion would not produce equivalent results.

Comment: That behaviour as a whole seems *not* to comply with the standards. Once bound, `this` cannot be overriden (no matter who the invoker is, `instanceof` the origin or not). So there should be no case where `oThis` isn't used (making the condition at best unnecessary and at worst non-standard).

Answer (score 0):

```
// check to see if the native implementation of bind already
// exists in this version of JavaScript. We only define the
// polyfill if it doesn't yet exist.

if (!Function.prototype.bind) {

  // creating the bind function for all Function instances by 
  // assigning it to the `Function.prototype` object. Normally 
  // you would avoid assigning to builtin prototypes because you
  // may cause a conflict with new features, but here this is a
  // known feature that is already in the spec that we're adding
  // to a JavaScript runtime that is not up to spec, so its ok

  Function.prototype.bind = function (oThis) {

    // if you attempt to call this function from a non-function object
    // for example if you assign this bind function to a normal object
    // or use `call`/`apply` to change the context of this function call to
    // a non function value (e.g. `Function.prototype.bind.call({})`), we
    // throw an error because bind can only work on functions, and we
    // require that `this` in this call is a function

    if (typeof this !== "function") {
      throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");
    }

    // bind does two things, it binds a context (`this` value) to a
    // function for when its called, and it provides a way to bake in
    // some pre-defined arguments that are automatically passed into 
    // that function when called. Those arguments can be passed into
    // the bind call and get picked up here as `aArgs` pulling them
    // from `arguments` making sure to lop off the `oThis` value

    var aArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),

      fToBind = this, // this is the function we're binding
      fNOP = function () {}, // a constructor used for `new` usage (see below)

      // `fBound` is the bound function - the result that bind is going to
      // return to represent the current function (`this` or `fToBind`) with
      // a new context.  The idea behind this function is that it will simply
      // take the original function and call it through `apply` with the
      // new context specified.

      fBound = function () {

        // call the original function with a new context using `apply`.
        // however if the function is called with `new`, it needs to be called
        // with the context of, and return, a new object instance and not the
        // bound version of this.  In that case, binding gets ignored in favor
        // of using the `this` of the new instance rather than the `oThis` binding.

        // new object instances inherit from the prototype of their constructors.
        // Our `fBound` function is supposed to mimic the original with the
        // exception of a change in context.  So if new objects are created with
        // it, they should behave as though they were created from the original.
        // But at the same time, we can't simply carry over the prototype of the
        // original into `fBound` because it is a separate function and needs its
        // own prototype, just one that also inherits from the original. To
        // accommodate this, the `fNOP` function (constructor) above is used as
        // an intermediary for creating `fBound`'s prototype while allowing it to
        // be unique but also inherit the original.  And because that becomes part
        // of the bound function's prototype chain, it can be used to determine
        // whether `this` in `fBound` is an instance created by `new` or not since
        // `instanceof` works through a prototype chain lookup.

        return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP
               ? this
               : oThis,

               // call the function with arguments that include the added 
               // arguments specified from the original bind call plus
               // the arguments this function was called with

               aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
      };

    // `fNOP`'s use to provide an intermediary prototype between `fBound` and
    // the current function instance mimics `Object.create`. But we're assuming
    // if you don't have `bind`, you probably don't have `create` either, so do
    // it the old fashioned way with a constructor.  This works by setting the
    // constructor's prototype to the to-inherit-from constructor's (this)
    // prototype. A check is needed to prevent assinging that prototype to null
    // if it doesn't exist on this function (Function.prototype is technically
    // a valid target for `bind()` because it is a function but one that does not
    // have its own prototype).

    if (this.prototype) {
      fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;
    }

    // here the inheritance is made.  As a new function, `fBound` has no existing
    // inheritance chain to worry about, so we can easily replace it with a new
    // one - that of a new instance `fNOP`.  Since `fNOP`'s prototype is the original
    // function's prototype, `fBound` has a prototype which directly inherits from
    // that, one level between new instances and the original prototype. So
    // `fBound.prototype.__proto__ === this.prototype` and new instances of `fBound`
    // created with `new fBound()` will inherit from `fBound.prototype` as well as
    // the original function's prototype.

    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    // return the bound version of the function as
    // the result of the bind call

    return fBound;
  };
}
```